# Selenium on Jenkins: IE is not launching

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to a run a simple Selenium TestSuite through Jenkins. The TestSuite should run against IE.  I have already downloaded the IEDriver Server and included it in my "PATH" Variable too.

However, the problem is that once I trigger the build, the process seems to halt at the point where IE should launch and forever remains in that mode. One of the posts here suggested that I should use *iexploreproxy or *piiexplore. But even these did not work for me and continued to give the same result.

On the Selenium group issues, though this was reported, I wasn't able to make much sense of the fix that they said has been provided.  In any case that isn't working for me! Can someone please suggest how I can resolve this issue?

The command I am giving is: `java -jar C:\Selenium_RC\selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "http://www.google.com" "C:\Documents and Settings\PraveenS\Desktop\Daon_Projects\NSTIC\Selenium\TestSuite_Ex1.html" "C:\JenkinsSeleniumResults.html"`   in the Execute Windows Batch Command

Comment: Also... it works fine if I use Firefox! i.e: *firefox

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution by adjusting some registry settings regarding user control of IE.

Modify the registry to include the following key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

you might also have to add one to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry too (otherwise the same path as above).

After they key is added, add a DWORD to the key for "iexplore.exe", and set the value to "0".

Hope this gets you up and running.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. But can you please elaborate on the details. I can see that there is already an entry for FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAE_PASSWORD_DISABLE in both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as well as in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. But what should be the KEY Value?

Comment: In the HKEY_CURRENT_USER section the FEATURE_HTTP..._DISABLE has only one entry - Default of type REG_SZ and the value is not set for this. For the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE section it contains 3 entries Default.. (same as earlier), clview.exe of type REG_DWORD Data value is set to 1, and OUTLOOK.EXE of type REG_DWORD Data value set to 1.

Comment: Okie.. here's what I did.. I right clicked on the FEATURE_..._DISABLED and selected the DWORD option. I've specified the value as iexplore.exe and the default value it had set to was 0 so I have left it as it is. Hope this is the correct procedure and am gonna try it now!

Comment: Hi Strahlee... :( Sadly.. that didn't work too. I am using Jenkins 1.499 version on Windows XP SP3 machine. Could you please let me know if there are any other possibilities?